# Warnings vs optimization gcc

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I wonder if the warnings reported by compiler such as variable unused or control reaches end of a non-void function can impact a program (i.e crash) when the optimization is enabled (O2 or O3)

Could you please give me some examples ?

Comment: Well, "control reaches end of a non-void function" causes undefined behavior, you may want to fix it before thinking about optimizations.

Comment: You're looking for an example of a compiler diagnostic that is not accompanied by a program failure with optimizations turned off, but that is accompanied by a  program failure when optimizations are turned on?

Comment: Unused variable, no. Not returning a value from a function that requires it, yes, and it has nothing to do with optimization, it's always wrong.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but having a function that should return a pointer or a reference but doesn't will have UB when trying to use the return value.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/rx4b9PbaT <- example, try turning optimizations on/off or switching compilers

Comment: @Ian4264 you should definitely experiment a bit around this. You might be in for a bit of a surprise at what actually happens.

Comment: Thank you all for your help @dratenik good example I get from you the best response

Comment: @dratenik That's a nice example. The compiler seems to argue `foo` has no `return` statement, so it cannot ever return. Therefore `main` can't reach the `printf` after the `foo` call or return ever either. Therefore no `ret` instruction for `main` is needed. Then it just so happens that the linker will put `_start` directly after `main` in the binary and so the program keeps flowing back into `_start` and `main`.

Comment: Control reaching end of a non-void function (other than `main()`) results in undefined behaviour,   One possible symptom (which DOES occur in the real world) of undefined behaviour is observable changes of program behaviour associated with different optimisation settings.   Ergo, yes, compiler warnings can be associated with situations in which optimisation settings change observable program behaviour.      That association is not, however, guaranteed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Warnings indicate likely mistakes in your code. However, whether or not the warning is there or whether or not optimizations are enabled doesn't affect whether the code is correct.

Warnings such as `unused variable` simply indicate that you probably meant to use the variable somewhere but forgot to do so. Otherwise there wouldn't be a reason for the variable to be there.

Warnings such as `control reaches end of a non-void function` are more severe. For example in this specific case, calling a function with non-void return type causes *undefined behavior* if its execution reaches the function body's closing `}` without returning via a `return` statement prior to that.

In this case the warning is informing you that the compiler detected a path that the function could take for some input with this result. This is very likely unintended, because if you call that function taking that path, then your program would have undefined behavior.

---

When the program has *undefined behavior* you cannot be sure what it will do, absent additional guarantees made by your compiler/platform. It may behave in one way with optimizations and in a different way without them. It might also have different behavior with different compiler versions or just between different compilation runs or even program executions.

Higher optimization levels are however more likely to yield unexpected behavior in such a situation, because the compiler tries harder to transform the code into a more performant form and in doing so it will make assumptions on code constructs to not yield undefined behavior to expand the range of possible transformations.

Comment: I have seen code with unused variables that changed behaviour when those unused variables were removed i.e. removing those variables exposes other program bugs.  Such a situation occurs, for example, if some code is running past the end of an array - and adding a variable (that is otherwise unused) changes the symptom (e.g.  changes memory layout of the program as a whole, or the "unused" variable is tromped by other code running past the end of an array).  Such situations can be quite unnerving e.g. if the unused variable is being tromped by code in a different function.